# Making Z-Table with while function

Tags: r, statistics

The teacher in our class, while teaching us about the `while` construct, illustrated it's use with an example of how to construct a multiplication table as follows:

```
A <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
i=1
j=1
while (i<=10) {while (j<=10) {A[i,j]=i*j
j=j+1}
i=i+1
j=1  
}
A
```

So I then tried to make a Z-Table with that function but with parameters ranging between 0 - 0.99. However, I'm not sure if the following code is correct:

```
B <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)

i=0
j=0
while (i<=0.9) {while (j<=0.09) {B[i,j]=integrate[(1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp^((-(mean(i+j)^2)/2))]
j=j+0.01
i=0
}
i=i+1
j=0
}
B
"Error in exp^((-(mean(i + j)^2)/2)) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator"
```

if you could help me on how to make that Z-table using a `while` construct  I'd be very grateful. Thanks..

Comment: There are multiple problems: For one, the syntax for `exp` is (like any other function call) `exp(x)` and not `exp^(x)`, then `integrate[]` looks wrong, should probably be `integrate()` but that would take a function and not a numeric...not sure what you want to do with this call...

Comment: Also you reset `i` an `j` to 0 in each iteration, and `while (i <= 0.9)` would evaluate to FALSE after the first iteration (because of `i <- i + 1`) if you didn't reset it. I'd suggest starting with the basics first and then step by step, as you are more familiar with the language, build this up...

Comment: Thanks for the tips. So do you have any idea how to make that z table in that function?

Answer (score 1):

I cheat a little by using the `dnorm` function within the `integrate` function.

```
Z_table <- function(zmax=0.99, decimal=4){
  i <- 1; j <- 1
  z1.max <- trunc(zmax*10)/10 # First decimal place of z
  z2.max <- trunc(zmax*100)/100 - z1.max  # Second decimal place of z
  n <- length(seq(0, z1.max, 0.1)) * 10
  B <- matrix(rep(0, n), ncol=10)
  colnames(B) <- c("0.00", seq(0.01, 0.09, by=0.01))
  rownames(B) <- c("0.0", seq(0.1, z1.max, by=0.1))
  z1 <- 0 
  while(z1 <= z1.max) {  
    z2 <- 0
    while(z2 <= 0.09) {
      B[i, j] <- round(integrate(dnorm, -Inf, z1 + z2)$value, decimal)
      z2 <- z2 + 0.01
      j <- j + 1
    }
    i <- i + 1
    z1 <- round(z1 + 0.1, 1) # takes care of rounding errors
    j <- 1
  }
  cat("Probabilities are between -Inf and z\n")
  B
}
```

---

```
> Z_table()
Probabilities are between -Inf and z
      0.00   0.01   0.02   0.03   0.04   0.05   0.06   0.07   0.08   0.09
0.0 0.5000 0.5040 0.5080 0.5120 0.5160 0.5199 0.5239 0.5279 0.5319 0.5359
0.1 0.5398 0.5438 0.5478 0.5517 0.5557 0.5596 0.5636 0.5675 0.5714 0.5753
0.2 0.5793 0.5832 0.5871 0.5910 0.5948 0.5987 0.6026 0.6064 0.6103 0.6141
0.3 0.6179 0.6217 0.6255 0.6293 0.6331 0.6368 0.6406 0.6443 0.6480 0.6517
0.4 0.6554 0.6591 0.6628 0.6664 0.6700 0.6736 0.6772 0.6808 0.6844 0.6879
0.5 0.6915 0.6950 0.6985 0.7019 0.7054 0.7088 0.7123 0.7157 0.7190 0.7224
0.6 0.7257 0.7291 0.7324 0.7357 0.7389 0.7422 0.7454 0.7486 0.7517 0.7549
0.7 0.7580 0.7611 0.7642 0.7673 0.7704 0.7734 0.7764 0.7794 0.7823 0.7852
0.8 0.7881 0.7910 0.7939 0.7967 0.7995 0.8023 0.8051 0.8078 0.8106 0.8133
0.9 0.8159 0.8186 0.8212 0.8238 0.8264 0.8289 0.8315 0.8340 0.8365 0.8389

> Z_table(zmax=2.9, decimal=3)
```

Comment: This is the exact same thing what i want. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Kadir Aydin. Glad to help. ;)